# Stripe payment returns 400 code in node js but not through insomnia

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to perform small integration of Stripe without npm, so below is my helper snippet:

```
const https = require('https')
const config = require('./config')

const stripe = {}

stripe.makePayment = function(callback) {

    // configure the request payload
    const payload = {
        "amount" : 50,
        "currency" : "usd",
        "source" : "tok_visa",
        "description" : "Payment from NODE API"
    }

    // Configure the request details
    const requestDetails = {
        'protocol': 'https:',
        'hostname': 'api.stripe.com',
        'method': 'POST',
        'path': '/v1/charges',
        'headers': {
            'Contenty-Type': 'application/w-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + config.stripe.key
        }
    }

    // Instantiate the request object
    var req = https.request(requestDetails, function(res){
        // Grab the status of the sent request
        var status = res.statusCode
        // Callback successfully if the request went through
        if(status == 200 || status == 201){
            callback(false)
        }else {
            callback("Status code returned was"+status)
        }
    })

    // Bind to the error event so it doesn't get thrown
    req.on('error', function(e){
        callback(e)
    })

    // Add the payload
    req.write(JSON.stringify(payload))

    // End the request
    req.end()

}

module.exports = stripe
```

I call the make payment function inside index.js like this:

```
const stripe = require('./lib/stripe')

stripe.makePayment(function(err){
    console.log(err)
})
```

When I run the index file, I get a 400 response.

NOTE: My post request is successful when I try on Insomnia. I use Bearer api_token as authorization, and form URL encoded content type.

Stripe documentation link [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create)

What can possibly be wrong with my POST request?

My full index file can be found here [enter link description here](https://jsbin.com/pesujezihi/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

> What can possibly be wrong with my POST request

What is the full error message that comes with that 400 response? Stripe typically includes good messaging on malformed requests to help you figure out what needs to change.

Separately, have you looked at using the official [node client](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node)? It might simplify some of your code:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_123');
const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 2000,
  currency: 'usd',
  source: 'tok_visa',
  description: 'using stripe-node!',
});
```

Comment: the idea is to do the work without any libraries. Unfortunately

Comment: Ok, sure, raw HTTP requests should work fine. What's the complete error message?

Comment: am struggling to find which property display the message.
So far I could only access the statusCode property